# How to alter the column in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I am using laravel and mysql database ,i want to change the column type and data what ever present inside the database can you please help me to acheive this one..

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

// DB::query("ALTER TABLE `users`.`percentage` CHANGE COLUMN `percentage/100` Decimal(23,4) NUllable ;");

$table->decimal('percentage')->storedAs("'percentage' / 100");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Question: Updating table schema without affecting data in Laravel

For example this is your database migrate file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('percentage');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class changeColumnUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->decimal('percentage', 23, 4)->change();
        });

    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->decimal('percentage', 23, 4)->change();
        });
    }

}
```

Then migrate using the command,

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: It's not a column rename. Read the question correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry my apologies, I'll change my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the Laravel Documentation, there's a [Updating Column Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes)

But the thing is `->change()` doesn't work with `storeAs`, so you may want to use a raw query here:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `percentage` `percentage` DECIMAL(23,4) AS (('percentage' / 100)) STORED");
}
```

Comment: for example from UI i received a value like 12.34 in database also it's storing like this ,actually it should store 0.1234 rightt it's not storing like this with query

Comment: Apparently, `->change()` doesn't work with `storeAs`. You may want to use a raw query here. Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'percentage' (SQL: ALTER TABLE `users` C
HANGE `percentage` `percentage` DECIMAL(23,4) AS (('percentage' / 100)) STORED)
it's throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is official documentation of Laravel regarding this issue : [Updating Column Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes)